# How to Store This Data in the Database with the Textarea?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am getting this error message:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Hello World'; ?>')' at line 1
```

I am looking to store following data:

```
<?php echo 'Hello World'; ?>
```

This is my code:

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $post = $_POST['post'];


    $tqs = "INSERT INTO ttn03 (post) VALUES ('$post')";

    $tqr = mysqli_query($dbc, $tqs) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));

    echo "The data has gotten successfully added.";
}
```

Using these two did not work for me:

```
htmlspecialchars();
htmlentities();
```

This is the HTML form:

```
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
    <textarea name="post" value=""></textarea>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

The database collation is on:

```
utf8_unicode_ci
```

This is in my header:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: **STOP THROWING DATA IN SQL QUERIES.** I don't know who gave you the idea of throwing `$post` data directly in SQL, but he should be shot.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the code should look like:

```
// first of all, make sure 'post' is set - don't let PHP guessing what to when it's not set.
if(isset($_POST['post'])){
    $post = $_POST['post'];
}else{
    $post = '';
}

// this is your SQL QUERY. Never, ever, ever, throw data in sql queries
$tqs = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO ttn03 (post) VALUES (?)');

// this is how to pass data to the statement
$statement->bind_param('s', $post);

// execute the statement and prints errors
if(!$statement->execute()){
    die('Error '. $mysqli->errno .': '. $mysqli->error);
}

// close statement
$statement->close();
```

---

You can find some excellent documentation and examples here:

http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/basic-php-mysqli-usage